# How do I add ILogger<T> as a DI when using MapGroup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using NET7 Minimal API (going from controllers). When using the ApiController you can just add the ILogger with the classname when injecting, it is still the case for when using app.Map. How do I use ILogger when using MapGroup (app.MapGroup("/api").MapWeatherForecast())

I am getting: 'MapWeatherForecastEndpoint': static types cannot be used as type arguments

```
public static class MapWeatherForecastEndpoint
{
    public static RouteGroupBuilder MapWeatherForecast(this RouteGroupBuilder buider)

    {
        buider.MapGet("/", WeatherForecast);

        return buider;
    }

    public static IResult WeatherForecast(ILogger<MapWeatherForecastEndpoint> logger,ISomeServices someServices)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("test");
        return TypedResults.Ok("WeatherForecast");
    }
}
```

**Edit**: updated the example and added the error.

Comment: did you try using `[FromServices]`

Comment: It wouldn't work. I should have specified the error in the questions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a static class as a type argument. You can use `ILoggerFactory` to achieve your requirement:

```
public static class MapWeatherForecastEndpoint
{
    public static ILogger _logger;

    public static RouteGroupBuilder MapWeatherForecast(this RouteGroupBuilder buider)

    {
        buider.MapGet("/", WeatherForecast);

        return buider;
    }

    public static IResult WeatherForecast(ILoggerFactory logger,  ISomeServices someServices)
    {
        _logger = logger.CreateLogger("MapWeatherForecastEndpoint");
        _logger.LogInformation("test");
        return TypedResults.Ok("WeatherForecast");
    }
}
```

It will log like:

[image]